# LINQ to Dataset - equivalent of sql (where ... in...)

Tags: linq

I have a list of customer id's, custList(of string).

I want to use a LINQ query to a Dataset, to get all customers in the customer table, where customerID is "IN" my custList(of string).

Is this possible in LINQ? I have searched online and not found the answer. I'm new to LINQ..

Thanks

Comment: Thanks all for your speed responses!! I ended up using:                 Dim query1 = From record In ds.Tables("Customers").AsEnumerable() _
Where lst.Contains(record.Field(Of String)("custID"))
                       Select record

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to upvote useful answers and mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var custList = new HashSet<string>() { "a", "b", "c"...};

from record in table.ToEnumerable()
where custList.Contains(record.Field<string>("customerID"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In LINQ you use the `Contains()` method to perform these kind of queries.

I don't know LINQ to DataSets, but in LINQ to SQL you can do the following:

```
var statuses = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

var query = from p in dataContext.Products
            where statuses.Contains(p.Id)
            select p;
```

This should generate SQL similar to:

```
select * from Product p
where p.Id in (1, 2, 3)
```

*(Note how it feels back-to-front in the LINQ code to the generated SQL - that's why if you know SQL well it's not very intuitive, but it makes very elegant use of existing .NET language features)*

This also typically works for `string` and collections of some other basic types that L2S knows about because they're in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
var custList = new HashSet<int> { 10, 15, 17 };
CustomerSet.Where(c => custList.Contains(c.CustomerID));
```